# QWSServer::sendKeyEvent equivalent in Qt5

Tags: qt

I am porting some old Qt4.8 code to Qt5.6. I am not Qt expert but QWS server support is removed from the latest Qt5 core.

In my old code I have areas where it talks to QWSServer to send key events.
See below:

```
QWSServer::sendKeyEvent(Unicode, KeyCode, Qt::NoModifier, true, false);
QWSServer::sendKeyEvent(Unicode, KeyCode, Qt::NoModifier, false, false);
```

I had a look at QWSServer code that calls the `sendKeyEvent` method, and I can see that it generates an event to window focused.

Does anyone have a quick answer how to replace the above methods of QWSServer `sendKeyEvent` with a standard Qt5 method?

Comment: I think you need to describe in more detail how your scenario looks like. It is true that QWS is gone. Onto which target are you porting? Wayland? Qtwayland? X11? Eglfs?

Comment: I am using Eglfs. Unfortunately not many examples in Qt Embedded on how to transition from the Qt4 QWS, to QT5. It must be simple, simply don't know. It is a custom Widget that has to emit key  values  I suppose. QWS was doing that.

Comment: QWS was mostly intended for a multi process scenario. Eglfs is intended for a single process scenario. Single/multiprocess as in a single or multiple processes with graphical output.

Comment: So the question is what kind of scenario do you actually have process wise?